# How to return Json data from MVC Controller in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using a Repository pattern with Entity Framework, When i run my code instead of Json Data I am getting **-> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MovieInfo.Core.Models.Models.User]**

**Repository**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> Get();

    T GetDetails(Guid Id);

    void Insert(T data);

    void Delete(T data);

    void Update(T data);

    void Save();
}

public GenericRepository()
        {
            context = new Entities();
            dbEntity = context.Set<T>();
        }
```

**Services**

```
public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public TestService(
           IRepository<User> userRepository
           )
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        private readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;

        public IEnumerable<User> Get()
        {

            var result = _userRepository.Get();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(ITestService testService)
    {
        _testService = testService;
    }

    private readonly ITestService _testService;

    public IEnumerable<User> Index()
    {
        var result = _testService.Get();

        return result;
    }
}
```

I found some solution on here (StackOverflow) that I need to add WebApiConfig, I added as below but it also not work. I am getting the output 
**System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MovieInfo.Core.Models.Models.User]**

```
 public static class WebAppConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Remove(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                id = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Here is my Git Repository Link** 
https://github.com/Harshk16/MovieInfo

Please help me out how to get output in Json Format

Comment: Where and when are you getting that output ? What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: Instead of inheriting your Home controller with `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`, you must inherit it with `System.Web.Http.ApiController`

Comment: @Shyju I want last output result as json
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MovieInfo.Core.Models.Models.User] is my output result
I also added my git repo link

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan can you please give me some example,I also added my git repo link above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return JSON response form your MVC controller action method, you may use the `Json` method.

The `Json` method is defined inside `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`, from which you are inherting your `HomeController`. So you have access to this method.

The `Json` method returns `JsonResult` typw. So make sure your method's return type is either `JsonResult` or `ActionResult`. (The `JsonResult` class inhertis from `ActionResult`)

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var result = _testService.Get();
    return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Or

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = _testService.Get();
    return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Another option is to use a web api controller instead of MVC controller. Register your web api routes before your MVC action method routing in your `global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebAppConfig.Register);

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    // Your other existing code
}
```

and create a webapi controller which inherits from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`. Here I removed the Dependency Injection part for simplicity. You can wire up DI in your web api controllers by following the [AutoFac web api integration tutorial](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#quick-start)

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<User> Get()
    {
        var result = new List<User>
        {
            new User { Id = Guid.NewGuid() , DisplayName = "Shyju"},
            new User { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), DisplayName = "Scott"}
        };
        // Hard coded list of users. 
        // Once you fix your DI setup, you can use your service to get data.
        return result;
    }
}
```

By default, web api uses content negotioation. It reads the "Accept" request header value and based on that execute the corresponding formatter. **With your current web api routing template**, you can access this endpoint with the below request URL

```
http://yourSiteBaseUrl/api/users/get
```

If you do not want the `get` in your API Urls, simply fix your route template when registering the web api routing

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
```

Comment: Instead of writing to every controller i want to make it generic

Answer (score 1):

To use the web api, which you define in your WebApiConfig, your controllers need to inherit from the Web Api base controller `ApiController` instead of the MVC base controller `controller`.

When inheriting from the ApiController, the default Formatter will take care of turning your controller methods output to your desire result. In your case, as you removed the Xml-formatter, the default will be Json.

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public HomeController(ITestService testService)
    {
        _testService = testService;
    }

    private readonly ITestService _testService;

    public IEnumerable<User> Index()
    {
        var result = _testService.Get();

        return result;
    }
}
```